# Solve for $\theta$: $2 \sin \theta = 2 - \cos \theta$

Tags: trigonometry

Actually , I'm new to trigonometry .. So i want help in this question

> $$2 \sin \theta = 2 - \cos \theta $$

My attempt ->

$$\begin{align}
2 \sin \theta &= 2 - \cos \theta \\
2 \sin \theta &= 2 - {(1-\sin^{2}\theta)}^{1/2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Put the square-root term alone on one side and square both sides. This should give you a quadratic in $\sin x$ which can be solved either by factoring or the quadratic formula.

Comment: Move square root factor to one side of equation with other terms on other side square both sides and find a quadratic

Answer (score 5):

Beware that substituting $\cos\theta$ with $\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$ is not correct. Beware also that squaring will add spurious solutions.

---

Here's a method: set $x=\cos\theta$ and $y=\sin\theta$, so you have
$$
\begin{cases}
2y=2-x \\[4px]
x^2+y^2=1
\end{cases}
$$
This basically transforms the problem into finding the intersection of a line with a circle.

Solving the first with respect to $x$ gives $x=2-2y$, so
$$
4-8y+4y^2+y^2=1
$$
becomes
$$
5y^2-8y+3=0
$$
yielding
$$
y=\frac{3}{5}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
y=1
$$
The first solution gives $x=4/5$ and the second solution gives $x=0$. Finally you have
$$
\theta=\arcsin\frac{3}{5}+2k\pi \quad(k\text{ an integer})
$$
or
$$
\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi \quad(k\text{ an integer})
$$

Comment: +1 for geometric interpretation. With this in mind, it is clear that there will be 0, 1 or 2 solutions and one can also simply conclude why there will be precisely 2 solutions without even starting to compute them (of course, up to periodicity).

Comment: +1.  And to clarify, the substitution $\cos\theta = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2\theta}$ is incorrect because technically $\cos\theta = \pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$.  In this case it will work out fine anyway because we eventually square it, but it is best to avoid incorrect steps that lead to correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Either use [Weierstrass Substitution](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Weierstrass_Substitution)  to form a Quadratic Equation in $$\tan\dfrac\theta2$$

---

OR  $$\cos\theta=2(1-\sin\theta)$$

$$\cos^2\dfrac\theta2-\sin^2\dfrac\theta2=2\left(\cos\dfrac\theta2-\sin\dfrac\theta2\right)^2$$

We can take out $\cos\dfrac\theta2-\sin\dfrac\theta2$ as common factor.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score -1):

You may write $\sin(\theta)=\frac{2\tan(x)}{1+\tan^2(x))},\cos(\theta)=\frac{1-\tan^2(x)}{1+\tan^2(x)}$ where $2x=\theta$ As suggested by lab bhattacharjee its weierstrass substitution

Comment: This formally known as Weierstrass Substitution. See my answer.

Comment: Ya I'll add it.

Answer (score -2):

Another way to solve this problem is to divide both sides by $\cos \theta$.
$$2\sin\theta = 2 - \cos\theta$$
$$2 = 2\sin\theta + \cos\theta$$
$$\frac{2}{\cos\theta} = \frac{2\sin\theta + \cos\theta}{\cos\theta}$$
$$2\sec\theta = 2\tan\theta + 1$$
$$\sec\theta = \tan\theta + \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\sec^2\theta = (\tan\theta + \frac{1}{2})^2$$
$$\sec^2\theta = \tan^2\theta +\tan\theta + \frac{1}{4}$$
$$\sec^2\theta = (\tan^2\theta +1)-1+\tan\theta + \frac{1}{4}$$
$$\sec^2\theta = \sec^2\theta-1+\tan\theta + \frac{1}{4}$$
$$\tan\theta = \frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: You are missing out a $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ by doing this, though. (division by zero)

Comment: @Deepak Very true. $\tan\theta =\pm\infty$ needs to also be considered.